# Could not find file [Filename]

Tags: c#, file

I am getting error: Could not find file 'C:\Users\User\source\repos\YoutubeSubtitles\YoutubeSubtitles\bin\Debug\net7.0\client_secrets.json'.
However, I have this file in that directory
And the code of how use this file:

```cs
string filePath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\client_secrets.json";  

List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath).ToList();
```

I've tried it with different filename and file, and it doesn't help. I also have tried to Clean, Rebuild and restarting Visual Studio.

Update

---

This produces the same filePath: string filePath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "client_secrets.json"); and it didn't solve the issue

When i copied exact path from the error message and pasted it into adressbar, it found the file.

I also reproduced this issue in different project, and with different file in different location, I am getting the same error.

Comment: because \ are used to escape special characters in strings and to include a literal backslash in a file path, you need to escape it by using a double backslash \\.

Comment: @Freeman: There *is* a double-backslash otherwise it wouldn't even have compiled. It was just a matter of the code not being properly formatted.

Comment: ok so she can use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` instead to get the base directory of the application:
`string filePath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "client_secrets.json");`

Comment: I strongly suspect that file really *doesn't* exist at the time you're running it - I've never seen `File.ReadAllLines` complain about a file not existing when it does. It's hard to help further to be honest. One thing you could try doing is *writing* to the file you're actually expecting to read, then looking in Windows Explorer to see what's in the directory.

Comment: @Freeman: But the question claims that the file exists in the directory - which would suggest it's not a matter of the directory being wrong.

Comment: OT json is best handled as a single string, instead of a list of lines

Comment: If `File.ReadAllLines` tells you a file doesn't exist, it most certainly doesn't exist at the time, this code is exected. There is no point in insisting that the file exists. Rather check if you are looking at the correct path or - as your directory seems to be a buildtarget -  if the directory has been cleaned out by the build and that file was removed.  Also try copying the exact path from the error message and pasting it in the addressbare of an explorer window. What happens?

Comment: @derpirscher When i copied exact path from the error message and pasted it into adressbar, it found the file.

Comment: @Freeman This produces the same filePath: string filePath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "client_secrets.json"); and it didn't solve the issue

Comment: set a breakpoint in your code at the line with `File.ReadAllLines` when the program halts copy the content of the `filePath` variable and try to access that path in explorer. Or try opening that exact filename in windows notepad. Or another possibility: Is this program running under a different user that may not have permissions to access that folder/file?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the extension of file to the name, so it was basically client_sercets.json.json

Answer (score -1):

In C# strings, the backslash () is used as an escape character. To include a literal backslash in a file path, you need to escape it by using a double backslash (). So, the correct way to construct the file path is like below.

```cs
string filePath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\client_secrets.json";
```

The double backslashes in the file path are essential for the code to compile correctly. If you use a single backslash, it will result in a compilation error due to the escape character syntax. So, using double backslashes is necessary for the code to work as intended.
In summary, ensuring the proper use of double backslashes in the file path will likely resolve the issue you're facing with the "Could not find file" error.

Comment: Better: use `Path.Combine`.

Comment: As `\c` is not a valid escape sequence, `"\client_secret.json"` would lead to a compile error. So it's quite safe to assume, there are indeed to backslashes in the original code.  And that there is a wellformed path in the error message supports this even more ...